# Can a verb be followed by an adjective?

Tags: adjective-position

I see this sentence "In order to explore this city unencumbered, I left my luggage at the station"
Why is an adjective "unencumbered" used here? I think it should be changed into "uncencumberedly" because adverb grammatically follows verb.

Comment: "Unencumbered" is an adjective serving as a predicative adjunct: predicative because it relates to a predicand (the covert subject "I", or "me"), and an adjunct because it's a modifier in clause structure, i.e. it's part of the verb phrase "to explore this city unencumbered".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually "unencumbered" *doesn't* modify the verb "explore" here in this sentence.

The verb "left" **causes** the adjective condition "unencumbered", so the adjective modifies the noun as subject in this case.
So now we are actually saying "I left my luggage at the station to explore this city, feeling unencumbered."

Please correct me if it's a misconception. Thx mates.

P.S. Here is some other people discussing the same grammar question about *verb followed by adjective*: [Action Verb followed by Adjective?](https://www.usingenglish.com/forum/threads/121878-quot-Action-Verb-followed-by-Adjective-quot)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is it an predicative adjective?

Comment: Yes it can be used as a predicative adjective. Example: "When you want to try all manner of wicked and wild moves on the surfboard, you need a good pair of freestyle board shorts to let you do whatever you want while feeling completely unencumbered." Just feel free to use it :)

Comment: And what kind of this sentence? I want to learn more about it.

Comment: _Left_ has nothing to do with it here. You’re correct that _unencumbered_ modifies the subject (which is _I_ in the matrix clause), but it would do regardless of which verb happened to be in the matrix clause.